# Python default parameter with format()

Tags: python

I have a Python question regarding default parameter value:

---

```
def command(one="Number 1", a = "{one} .. {two}"):
     two = "Number 2"
     a.format(one=one, two=two)
     return a
print command()
```

---

Actual Output: {one} .. {two}

Desired Output:
Number 1 .. Number 2

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks

Followed-up questions:

### ******

```
import logging
import sys

def command(one="Number 1", a = "{one} .. {two}"):
    two = "Number 2"
    a = a.format(one=one, two=two)           
    logging.error(a)        # Will print
    #logging.debug(a)        # Will not print

command()
```

---

Why logging.error will print, but logging.debug won't print? I thought debug level is lower than that of error, and it should print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
    a.format(one=one, two=two)
```

is the problem. Since `str`ings are immutable, what happens on this line is the interpreter formats the way you expected it to, but it doesn't assign the value back to `a` (strings are immutable).

So when you

```
    return a
```

Your `a` is still the unformatted `a` from before.

The solution is to combine these two lines into

```
    return a.format(one=one, two=two)
```

In response to the follow-up question:

`logging.debug(whatever)` may not show up because `logging` may not have been configured to show the `DEBUG` level. To correct this, use the `basicConfig` function:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, see followed-up question.

Comment: Check the edit for a solution to the follow-up question

Answer (score 4):

You need to either reassign `a` to `a = a.format(one=one, two=two)` or simply return it.

```
return a.format(one=one, two=two)
```

`a.format` does not change the original string `a`, strings are **immutable** so all `a.format` does is create a new string. Any time you modify a string it creates a new object. Unless you are using concatenation then to change the value of  `a` you need to reassign `a` to the new object.

`str.replace` is another example where people get caught:

```
In [4]: a = "foobar"

In [5]: id(a)
Out[5]: 140030900696000
In [6]: id(a.replace("f","")) # new object
Out[6]: 140030901037120
In [7]: a = "foobar"     
In [8]: a.replace("f","")
Out[8]: 'oobar'
In [9]: a  # a still the same
Out[9]: 'foobar'
In [10]: id(a)
Out[10]: 140030900696000
In [11]: a = a.replace("f","") # reassign a 
In [12]: id(a) 
Out[12]: 140030900732000    
In [13]: a 
Out[13]: 'oobar'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `str.format` doesn't modify the string. It only returns a new modified string based on its arguments. So what you really want is something like this:

```
def command(one="Number 1", a = "{one} .. {two}"):
     two = "Number 2"
     return a.format(one=one, two=two)

print command()
```

In Python, none of the `str` and `string` functions actually modify the strings that they work on and tend to return new strings instead. This is because strings are immutable, i.e. they can't be modified.